# WooCommerce products not showing in shop after variations updated from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a CSV file which is updated hourly from a warehousing system that contains all the SKUs and stock totals of products in my WooCommerce store. I've written a plugin to retrieve the stock CSV, loop through products & their variations in the store and update the `_stock_status` & `_stock` of products found.

All of this works fine, and the changes are shown accurately within the admin panel. However, products that were previously out of stock that have been updated to be in-stock do not show in any categories on the front-end, even though the visibility is set up correctly for the product (the same as it is for all others). Products that were previously in-stock and have only had their stock totals changed work fine. If I visit the product permalink directly, it works and I can add the item to my cart.

If I open up the product within the admin panel, and without changing 'Update' it, I can now see it within the shop as normal.

I've tried clearing transients & caches, replacing WooCommerce's own stock management functions with `update_post_meta` but nothing seems to work except the above mentioned  update action.

What am I missing?